# Azure table Client ExecuteQuery does it handle contunation token Automatically

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-sdk-.net

Does the .excuteQuery of tableClient handles continuation token automatically unlike Azure SDK 1.7

```
CloudTable tableReference = tableClient.GetTableReference(“XYYZ”);
tableReference.ExecuteQuery()
tableReference.ExecuteQuery<TResult>
tableReference.ExecuteQuery<TElement,TResult>
```

Is the above methods ExecuteQuery will handle Continuation token automatically in Azure SDK 2.4 , In the Previous versions i.e. 1.7 SDK,  If we forget to call .execute method of IQuerable there is chance of Continuation token not return to client (esp. in case of querying on multiple partitions where some partitions might not have data) . Is the same behavior appears in Current version of Azure SDK 2.4 also. Should we explicit call .execute()

Until I call For each or toList, Call is not made to server.  If the ContinationToken is not handled properly in the server side, is there way to enforce to send continuation token to client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEnumerable object returned by ExecuteQuery is a lazy enumerator and therefore does not actually make a request until it is enumerated. That is why foreach or ToList makes it execute the query and handle the continuation tokens. So, in short, you just need to go through the results.

Comment: Thanks Ozler, so continuation token handling is automatically taken care . Thanks for quick response.